# PHP / MySQL - returning the top 10 users by the amount of entries there are

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with a users id and shoe.

For each shoe a user gets an row in the db so a person with the id 5 might have 50 entries, a user id of 3 might have 23 entries and so on.

Im wondering how i would display the top 10 user ids based on the amount of shoes they have in the db?

Comment: what is content of shoe field?

Comment: I'm with Col. Shrapnel, the content of the database table was a bit ambiguous, but I made the assumption the table was a map of `user_id` and `shoe_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL code should resemble this:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS num_shoes FROM shoes GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY num_shoes DESC LIMIT 10
```

The key is the `GROUP BY` instruction, it tells MySQL to roll all the same user ID's into one entity.

Comment: what if I have entry as userid=3, shoe=3 || userid=3, shoe=5. Your query will return userid=3, count=2.... It should be SUM...

Comment: I don't understand the concern, the OP just wanted the top 10 user IDs based on the number of shoes they have.

Comment: This query worked perfect, although the comment above says i should use SUM instead of COUNT .. Is this right?

Comment: Absolutely not. If you used `SUM`, you would end up with a sum of each of the shoe IDs, not a count of them. So if you have `user_id = 3` owning 2 shoes with ID 4 and 8, the `SUM` for `user_id = 3` would return 12, instead of 2. Make sense?

Comment: @BigJobbies : Means on all row, you have data for Shoe as 1... right??

Comment: @BigJobbies can you tell the difference between **sum** and **count?**

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense, i just ran the SUM one on the database and it returned the result of counting the ID's, so the COUNT worked 100% perfect ... Thank you very much creanium

Answer (score -3):

Try this

`SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS shoes FROM table ORDER BY shoes DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: This wont work as it will display an id multiple times .... i want to be able to count the rows for an id, then display the top 10 ids